# Setting up polymorphic associations in db when the super is a FK of subclasses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, database-design, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

Using class table inheritance it is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554522/something-like-inheritance-in-database-design) that the subclass refers to the superclass and not the other way around.  Normally in Rails polymorphic associations work in the other direction--the super refers to the subclass.

Recommended

```
vehicle
  .id

car
  .vehicle_id # PK instead of using id (identity column)

boat
  .vehicle_id
```

Typical Rails polymorphic association

```
vehicle
  .id
  .subclass_type
  .subclass_id

car
  .id

boat
  .id
```

What I like about the recommended approach is that I can do away with having non-matching keys.  That is, a given car and its vehicle super share the same id.

In my particular instance, I will potentially support multiple inheritance and so, for example, I could have a hybrid car-boat vehicle.

Questions:

- How would you set up the ActiveRecord associations...

  - If a vehicle could have only one subclass?
  - If a vehicle could have many subclasses?  (The problem I see here is that by not specifying a specific subclass_type how do the associations know which table to hit.  I don't guess they would and so would have to hit all possible tables.  So maybe an intersection table would help here.)
- Is this a good design pattern for use with ActiveRecord or does it buck the Rails way enough that we should avoid it?

Comment: Rails, and thus ActiveRecord, is opinionated software. You class table inheritance is not part of that opinion. I think you're better off with STI and/or dynamically using modules into your Vehicle class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for the simplest solution: using a polymorphic association (as shown in the second block).  It will have better performance and be more maintainable.