# Suggestion for Database Integrity with Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

I try to create a database design to suit my needs.

I would really appreciate any of your recommendation for my following table design:

[image]

I have two components: **Categories** and **Content**.

Whenever I create a new item for any of those two components, a new route item should be created also, with relations like shown on visual diagram.

Red and Blue highlights are identical with their colors.

Is it good practice to have the following columns in those tables like `ci_routes.refid`, `ci_categories.slug` and `ci_content.slug` ?

**==== UPDATED ====**

The business logic for my app works like this:

- I create a category item with html form
- On form submit, app will create a new route to return a newly created `ci_routes.id`
- Category will be created and filled with all info including `ci_categories.rid`.
- Then it updates yet again the `ci_routes` with the all information where the `ci_routes.slug` is identical to `ci_categories.slug` and `ci_routes.route` will be based on configured setting something like `$path/$category_id` where `$path = 'category'`

Whenever I decide to change `$path` to something like `$path = 'node'`, all my routes should be purged and recreated based on new settings.

Pls correct me If I made some logical mistake somewhere in my logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it good practice to have the following columns in those tables 
>   ***ci_routes.refid***

No. In the current design ci_routes.refid will be a column referencing two tables, you can not have a foreign key to more than a table on a column in RDBMS, so you have to handle it in your application logic, that would be a buggy, hard work. Also you will loose data integrity in database level, that is not appreciated.
***Solution 1*:** 
 Have two separate columns in `ci_routes` to reference `ci_categories` and `ci_content` like `ci_routes.content_id` and `ci_routes.categories_id` 
***Solution 2*:** 
Use [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554522/something-like-inheritance-in-database-design) by having a base table for components and categories, containing shared properties of these two entities, having the base table you can refer it inside ci_routes as the foreign key. 
[image]

> Is it good practice to have the following columns in those tables like
>   ci_categories.slug and ci_content.slug ?

Answering the question needs more information about your business logic.
BTW it seams you are going to de-normalize your model by redundant `slug` column. If you are going to do this just for performance reason then think about when a components slug column is updating, you will need to update dependent rout row(s). I won't do that until having specific evidences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mohsen. The reason I have slug in both component tables is that if someday I decide to truncate the routes table to generate new values based on new settings, it will be a lot easier I guess. But maybe I miss something. I will update my question in a moment, to give you a better perspective about my business logic.

Comment: What will happen if you persist slug just inside Category and Component and removing it from routes?

Comment: i was wondering about the same, either left it inside `routes` and remove from components table, or like u said, remove it only from routes.