# How to visualize database tables schema in VS

Tags: database, visual-studio, schema

How do I display that schema of tables in my database and foreign keys that links them in VS ?

Example of such schema is used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database) question mattlant's answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They can be done through Visual Studio or the Sql Server Management Studio.

In visual studio just open the "Server Explorer" window, right-click on the Database Diagrams folder (under the db you want), and choose "Add Database Diagram", just drag-and-drop the tables you want onto the diagram.

Through Sql Server management studio there done the same way (just without the server explorer window).

Comment: The "Database Diagrams" folder is visible in the SSMS but not in the VS. It was apparently deprecated in VS 2012.