# Convert EER-Diagram/Generated Schema to ER Diagram

Tags: sql, database-design, erd, eer-model

I'm working on a school project that requires the creation of an ER diagram and a database schema that is derived from that diagram. The schema has some very stringent size requirements (no more than x number of tables). I'm running into an issue where some of my entities follow an "is-a" type relationship that is best described using the EER model, something we aren't allowed to use. Here's a very rough outline of what I'm trying to achieve:

I need to keep track of several unique [Part]s that have many (entirely unique attributes). They all share some attributes, like (QuantityInStock). I have [Machine]s that *use* any (quantity) of any of those different [Part]s.

If I follow the ER model, I believe the machines will have a separate M-to-N relationship with each unique part type. Each M-to-N relationship is supposed to translate into its own table. Because of the strict maximum number of tables we are allowed to have, this isn't possible.

If I follow the EER model, the translation process generates only one or two extra tables - not one more relation for each [Part].

What I need to accomplish is somehow convert the "is-a" relationship (i.e. [ThisPartType] "is-a" [Part]) into something that works within the ER model. I need some way to relate of the different unique parts to the machines that use those parts.

To give an example of what I'm going for:

- Machine A uses 30 of PartA[1], 47 of PartB[21], 22 of PartC[18], and 3 of PartD[54].
- Machine B uses 8 of PartC[12] and 1 of PartD[44].
- Machine C uses 1 of PartF[0] and 5 of PartZ[28].

I'd like to have access to the unique bits of information for PartB[21] (radius, threadwidth), as well query the heaviest of all the PartCs. But I also need to have the ability to assign these parts to the Machines in a way that doesn't need many more tables.

Comment: provide some links that describe these modelling types, or the differences between them.

Comment: That is actually a hard thing to find since the ER diagram notation isn't a standard (doubly so with EER). Wikipedia does provide a decent [overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model) of the ER model. It appears the EER model is only found within the textbook for the course. There is a very vague [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Entity-Relationship_Model) article on the subject. Sadly, this is one of those situations where a bit of required course material doesn't seem to be found too often in practice.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  Academic sources act as though these terms are well-known and well-defined, when in fact there are a million idiosyncratic variations and hybrids with no clear distinctions between them.  So... in order for us to help you, you'll have to give us more info about what you mean and need.

Comment: @PaulT.  Code format is for code, not for non-code.

Comment: What is the question? PS [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097)
[How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190296/3404097) [How to design a product table for many kinds of product where each product has many parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695752/3404097) etc etc etc [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]