# mysql query across three tables

Tags: php, mysql

The tables are `client`, `promo`, and `coupons`

`client` can have multiple `promo` and `promo` will have several `coupons.coupon_codes` and will have `coupons.copon_status`.

Now I want to perform a **delete** on a `client` but I want to check first that there are is no unused `coupons.coupon_code` on a `promo` based on the `coupons.copon_status` which would be 0 for unused and 1 for used.

I don't know how to make mysql table here so i have to write my question.

Comment: Can you edit your post with your tables structure. Would it be lot easier to help you. It seems that you need a `delete` statement with a `not in` in your `where` clause

Comment: You should look into Foreign Keys to handle the automatic deletion of relationships that exist between clients, promos and coupons.

Comment: yeah i would love to make a table structure but how? lurker problem, sorry.

Comment: If it is that you do not know how to create a MySQL database and it's tables ... use a tool like phpmysql or MySQL workbench or the mysql commandline tool. You can find out how to use them via web search. Once you have a database, you just use the respective approach to create your tables (i.e., table_client and fields clientId, clientName ..., table_promo and fields promoId, clientId, ..., table_coupons and fields couponId, promoId (and or clientId), coupon_codes, coupon_status ...

Comment: @nocturns2 no, i mean i don't know how to create a table here in stackoverflow to show my table.

Comment: here's a pretty simple example of illustrating a table from the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database