# EF6 and POCO Clarification

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, entity-framework-6

I am trying to get my head around how the following will work using EF6 and POCO.

I have the following classes:

```
public class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserLibrary> libraries{ get; set; }
}

public class UserLibrary {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AbstractLibrary> { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractLibrary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public List<LibraryType> LibraryType{ get; set; }

    public enum LibraryType{ }
}

public class LibraryB: AbstractLibrary
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public new List<LibraryType> LibraryType{ get; set; }

    public enum LibraryType
    {
        LibraryTypeAA,
        LibraryTypeAB,
        LibraryTypeAC
    }
}

public class LibraryB: AbstractLibrary
{
    public String y { get; set; }
    public new List<LibraryType> LibraryType{ get; set; }

    public enum LibraryType
    {
        LibraryTypeBA,
        LibraryTypeBB,
        LibraryTypeBC
    }
}
```

I have a number of concrete classes that extend AbstractLibrary and each has a different LibraryType enum.

The reasoning is that a User can have many UserLibrary, and a UserLibrary can have many concrete LibraryA, LibraryB (each having different properties, but all have LibraryType with different enum).

My question is: How does this translate to tables in EF, and how would I go on about listing all 'LibraryTypes' ?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Why does the base `LibraryType` exist at all? It seems to be quite useless.

Comment: How many implementations of `AbstractLibrary` are there? How flexible do you need to be in supporting more?

Comment: At the moment there are 3, but I wanted to make it such that if I wanted to add more it would be really simple.

Think of it like this, there is class A, class B, class C which all have their own specific enums (library type). On top of that, each may or may not have extra properties as required by the user requirements.

Comment: The reason of why LibraryType exists, is that I didnt want to create one concrete class per type.

What I could have done is have a class called LibraryTypeAA, which extends LibraryA which in turn extends AbstractLibrary. This, however, would lead to a nightmare.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: You did create one concrete enum per type, though. The enum `LibraryA.LibraryType` and the property `LibraryA.LibraryType` are in no way connected to `AbstractLibrary`'s parallel enum and property. They are completely separate, and the similar naming only serves to confuse, from what I can see. `((AbstractLibrary)libraryA).LibraryType` does **not** contain `libraryA.LibraryType`'s values.

Comment: Hmm thanks for letting me know! That was why I opened this kind of question as I am kind of confused on how inheritance, etc. works with EF.

I shall have a look at the post you mentioned above, but if you have any tutorials to point my way which I you recommend please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Sql Diagram.
[image]

Here's the code using Database First approach:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace EF6
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Library
    {
        public Library()
        {
            this.LibraryExtensionAs = new HashSet<LibraryExtensionA>();
            this.LibraryExtensionBs = new HashSet<LibraryExtensionB>();
            this.UserLibraries = new HashSet<UserLibrary>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LinkId { get; set; }

        public virtual LibraryTypeLink LibraryTypeLink { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<LibraryExtensionA> LibraryExtensionAs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<LibraryExtensionB> LibraryExtensionBs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserLibrary> UserLibraries { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace EF6
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class LibraryExtensionA
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LibraryId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LinkId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> x { get; set; }

        public virtual Library Library { get; set; }
        public virtual LibraryTypeLink LibraryTypeLink { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace EF6
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class LibraryExtensionB
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LibraryId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LinkId { get; set; }
        public string y { get; set; }

        public virtual Library Library { get; set; }
        public virtual LibraryTypeLink LibraryTypeLink { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace EF6
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class LibraryType
    {
        public LibraryType()
        {
            this.LibraryTypeLinks = new HashSet<LibraryTypeLink>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<LibraryTypeLink> LibraryTypeLinks { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace EF6
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class LibraryTypeLink
    {
        public LibraryTypeLink()
        {
            this.Libraries = new HashSet<Library>();
            this.LibraryExtensionAs = new HashSet<LibraryExtensionA>();
            this.LibraryExtensionBs = new HashSet<LibraryExtensionB>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Library> Libraries { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<LibraryExtensionA> LibraryExtensionAs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<LibraryExtensionB> LibraryExtensionBs { get; set; }
        public virtual LibraryType LibraryType { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace EF6
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.UserLibraries = new HashSet<UserLibrary>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UserLibrary> UserLibraries { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace EF6
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class UserLibrary
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LibraryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Library Library { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```