# One primary key for 2 entities (ERD)

Tags: database-design, primary-key, erd

I am drawing an ERD diagram for a hospital data base system scenario. In the database there are 2 types of doctors, one is a researcher and one is a practitioner. When drawing the ERD, I have created 2 different entities for them, and for the primary key I have given doctorID as the primary key for both the entities.

So my question is, is it possible to have one primary key for 2 entities?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I  suggest to  give some code samples, too, I makes much  easier to understand your  question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29).  You have a base Doctor entity, with the child Researcher and Practitioner types.  The primary key is on the base Doctor entity.

This is a  very useful post about how you can actually model these in a database:
[How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database?lq=1)