# How should i INSERT new data with TablePerType table structure?

Tags: sql, database, table-per-type

To 'emulate' inheritance in database i decided to use so called Table-Per-Type pattern (lerned recently [from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database)). I have the a Users with the most common colums for all users and i have a table Developers with additional info. This table is used to store some additional information about users whose role is developer.
There is Primary key `ID` for Users, which is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and also `ID` column in Developers table which is PK itself and also a FK referencing to `Users.ID`.

I am writing an SQL Query to populate my table with some test data. Trying to add new Developer i faced the problem: i do not understand how to INSERT new deverloper-user in both tables `Users` and `Developers`, because Users.ID is automatically generated and it must be equal to Developers.ID.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.  Some databases (such as Postgres) have direct support for inheritance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i am using INT datatype and using H2 database, i do not want to be bound to any specific SQL database implementation, if it is possible. I hope common SQL query will be ebough.

Comment: @Derp this functionality is especific to each vendor, even implamentation. Doing some generic sql procedure in standart t-sql to fit all won't be efficient, and kind of imposible.

Comment: You'll want to do an `insert` into users with an `output` clause into a (temp table/table variable).  You can then insert into developers using the outputted IDs and whatever other marker, but this is going to be implementation specific.  Postgres and Oracle use `returning`, SQL Server uses `output`, MySQL doesn't support either but might work with a trigger, etc...

Comment: You could also do 1 at a time inserts (ack!) and use your implementation's version of getting the last identity inserted, but again that's implementation specific - each one has a different way of capturing that in a scalar variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, long comment

@Derp this functionality is especific to each vendor, even implamentation. Doing some generic sql procedure in standart t-sql to fit all won't be efficient, and kind of imposible.

Try somthing generic as this, only work insertin one by one:

```
begin tran
insert table1
select top 1 @newId=IdentityColumn from table1 order by IdentityColumn desc
insert table2
commit
```