# How to structure the data model for profiles for user

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, code-first

In my application, a user can choose between 3 profiles to created.

For now, I have 3 tables in the database representing the profiles. One table for each profile.

But I don't know how to work with this In a proper way In the code.

Let say that I visit a profile by entering the following URL:

```
mysite.com/fishness
```

Either to get data from the database that belongs to the "fishness" profile, I must search In three tables. How should I do the search?
Should I just do three querys for each table? Or Is It a nicer way to do this?

Another thing Is when the user logs In. How should I get the profile that belongs to the user who logs in?
Should I have navigation properties In my `AppUser` model( the model for the user )?

The ugly thing In my opinion about this, Is that I must then add `navigation` properties for all three profiles In my `AppUser`.

Can anyone give me tips about how to design this?

Here Is my three profile tables:

**Profile1:**

```
Id
UserId (the users Id)
Name
CoverPicture
Description
WelcomePage
```

**Profile2:**

```
Id
UserId (the users Id)
Name
CoverPicture
Description
WelcomePage
```

**Profile3:**

```
Id
UserId
Firstname
Lastname
Birth
Profilepicture
WelcomePage
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of the 3 tables ?

Comment: @user3185569: Check my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You design is not good because it is not scallable , imagine you want to create a new profile , you will be obliged to create new table and edit your code .

My suggestion is to create a table `profile` and `user` , user has a column **profileId** that reference **profile** column id (foreign key) .

```
Table profile
ProfileID 
ProfileDesignation

Table user
UserId
Firstname
Lastname
Birth
Profilepicture
CoverPicture
Description
WelcomePage
ProfileID references profile.ProfileID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to be a classic case of "how do I implement inheritance in my database". There are several similar questions on SO; the best answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database/193222#193222).

As far as I understand, you have 3 types of profile. They each share some attributes (ID, UserID and WelcomePage), but each type may have attributes that are not shared (profile 1 and profile 2 look the same to me). That's a classic inheritance scenario.

There is no clean implementation in the relational model for this situation; instead, you must make trade-offs. Your current design is "table per concrete", and is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I created two sample table AppUser and UserProfile.Both tables are linked with foreign key AppuserId which is Primary key for Appuser.
[image]

If you want to create model for user Profile you can create separate classes per each table.when user login based on AppuserId you can access profile information.