# How can I make a list of a certain class, but still allow extensions of the class to be allowed in the list with all of their parameters C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am writing an item system for unity C#, and I have this base item class that I extend upon for different types of items, for example I would extend the base class and add a variable for attack and attack speed, and a function for attacking for a weapon class.
    But my issue is I am writing a database for the items, and I want to store these different classes into one big list, but when I make a list of Base Items, and I pass a weapon item, it cleaves away the attack function and the attack variables, and basically turns the weapon item into a base item, rendering it useless.

Comment: If you make the list as a List<Base> you don't know for certain that the item will be a weapon.  You'd need to retrieve the item from the list, cast it to weapon, then you'll have access to all of your weapon functions.

Comment: If I store a weapon in the list of List<Base> and will it still store the other functions and such?

Comment: I just that for a bow item, and tried to access the attack damage that I know is public after, and after doing this:

Debug.Log((BowItem)(itemDatabase[ind]).itemAttack);

It said 'BaseItem' does not contain a definition for 'projectile' and no extension method 'projectile' accepting a first argument of type 'BaseItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to rearrange your brackets slightly: `Debug.Log(((BowItem)itemDatabase[ind]).itemAttack);` Note the brackets are around `(BowItem)itemDatabase[ind]`, rather than just `itemDatabase[ind]`

Comment: THANK YOU, I still have to test it fully, but so far it seems that it will work!!!
THX!

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! THANK YOU THIS TOOK HOURS!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are into RDBMS, and not NOSQL, like SledgeHammer suggests, you will probably find you answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database).

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways of doing this in a relational database, which is what most common database systems are.

1. You can have different tables for each type of Item, so `Weapon`s have one table, `Potion`s have another, and the `Item` table is a list of `(Name, Type, Id)` tuples, telling you which item in which table to look at to get its exact details.  This *will* require one table for each class of item, but if you are careful, you only need a few.
2. Have an `Item` table, which stores an Item Type (again).  You also have an "Attribute" table, which has columns `ItemId, Attribute, Value`  So if you have a sword with speed 5 and damage 10, and a potion that heals 3, you would have the following rows

   ```
   Item
   ====
   Id | Name             | Category
   1  | "Sword"          | "weapon"
   2  | "Healing Potion" | "potion"

   Attribute
   =========
   ItemId | Attribute | Value
   1      | "speed"   | 5 
   1      | "damage"  | 10 
   2      | "healing" | 3
   ```

It's then up to you to `join` on ItemId, and [`pivot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the rows into columns and convert into your item's class.

Or you can use a document-based database, as the other answers suggest.

Comment: This will work too... Just be mindful of the real world scale. If you have a bunch of tables with hundreds of millions of rows and thousands of concurrent connections, your SQL will fall over while a document store with 100M docs wouldn't even break a sweat on a fraction of the hardware.

Comment: I'm writing my database as a list, is there any way to keep it like that?

Comment: @TehCosmicSloth You'd be better served by asking a new question, without referring to "Databases" at all - the word "database" has a specific meaning, and you want a different system.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a document store instead of a RDBS. RDBS requires all items in a table to be of the same type. The drawback is you end up with a bunch of NULL columns for the types that don't contain all the columns which makes everything hokey. A document store is schema-less, so you only have the attributes that pertain to the type.