# Best way to inherit with Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, inheritance

lets assume I have these classes

```
public class Animal {
    public int AnimalID;
    public bool HasFeet;
}

public class Dog {
    public int AnimalID;
    public int DogID;
    public bool HasOwner;
}

public class Cat {
    public int AnimalID;
    public int CatID;
    public bool LovesSleeping;
}
```

These classes are mirroring a Database Table.
What would be the best solution to get e.g. a Cat when only having the AnimalID? Checking the Table Dog if there is one with AnimalID I am looking for and then do the same with Table Cat would be totally ineffective.

How would the classes and the database look with the best solution?

Thanks for your help

## EDIT:

After some comments I saw I could implement it like that:

```
public class Animal {
    public int AnimalID;
    public bool HasFeet;
}

public class Dog : Animal {
    public bool HasOwner;
}

public class Cat : Animal {
    public bool LovesSleeping;
}
```

But now I wonder if I only have the AnimalID, how would I get the Cat with Linq2Sql?

Normally I would do something like

```
public static Animal Get(DataContext db, int animalID) {

    IQueryable<Animal> query =
    from animal in db.GetTable<Animal>()
    where animal.AnimalID == animalID
    select animal;

    return query.Single();
}
```

This will return me an Animal, but not a Cat I guess, right?
So how would I get the Cat if I don't know, the AnimalID is a cat?

Comment: Dog and Cat should inherit from Animal, they don't need separate `AnimalIDs`and you don't need DogID/CatID since those the the AnimalIds.

Comment: Are you asking for a database structure here? It's not clear.

Comment: If this classes mirrors tables on DB, so you can use only one table Animals with AnimalType column, it would be better in this situation

Comment: I edited the code a little to make it clearer what I mean. @IkramTurgunbaev if Dog and Cat do have different properties, your solution would not work anymore. But normally i would do this too

Comment: Unfortunately I voted to close as unclear, but this is really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By modeling your data like this you are creating an `Is-A` relationship. But as you already said you won't know which table the `Id` would belong.

```
public class Animal {
    public int AnimalID;
    public bool HasFeet;
}

public class Dog : Animal {
    public bool HasOwner;
}

public class Cat : Animal {
    public bool LovesSleeping;
}
```

Hence you can have tables like below for that relationship:

```
table Animal
------------
int Id (PK)
int Type
bit HasFeet

table Dog
---------
int Id (PK)
int AnimalId (foreign key to Animal.Id)
bool HasOwner

table Cat
---------
int Id (PK)
int AnimalId (foreign key Animal.Id)
bool LovesSleeping
```

When you apply this logic though it becomes a `Has-A` logic, but this doesn't hurt your requirement. So you can make a call only to `Animal` table, get the `Type` out of it, and make the next query against the related table to get the correct type of animal. This way you are still making 2 queries, but it won't increase when you add new types to your applications. Hence, this design also supports the Open-Closed principal.

Comment: Thank you, this seems a good starting point. Though I hoped there would be a solution without implementing a TypeID in the Animal Class, but this will work. Again: Thank you