# Best approach to implement inheritance in a data warehouse based on a postgres database

Tags: postgresql, database-design, data-warehouse, class-table-inheritance, multi-table-inheritance

I am developing a multi-step data pipeline that should optimize the following process:

**1) Extract data from a *NoSQL* database (*MongoDB*).**

**2) Transform and load the data into a relational (*PostgreSQL*) database.**

**3) Build a data warehouse using the *Postgres* database**

I have manually coded a script to handle steps 1) and 2), which is an intermediate ETL pipeline. Now my goal is to build the data warehouse using the *Postgres* database, but I came across with a few doubts regarding the DW design. Below is the dimensional model for the relational database:

[image]

There are 2 main tables, *Occurrence* and *Canonical*, from which inherit a set of others (drawn in red and blue, respectively). Note that there are 2 child data types, *ObserverNodeOccurrence* and *CanonicalObserverNode*, that have an extra many-to-many relationship with another table.

I made some [research](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105374/dimensional-model-for-inheritance-in-dimensions) regarding how inheritance should be implemented in a data warehouse and figured *the best practice would be to merge together the family data types (super and child tables) into a single table*. Doing this would imply adding extra attributes and **a lot** of *null* values. My new dimensional model would look like the following:

[image]

Question 1: Do you think this is the best approach to address this problem? If not, what would be?

Question 2: Any software recommendations for on-premise data warehouses? (on-premise is a must since it contains sensitive data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: @philipxy this is a "best design approach for a data warehouse based on a relational database that implements inheritance". Slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

Usually having fewer tables to join and denormalizing data will improve query performance for data warehouse queries, so they are often considered a good thing.

This would suggest your second table design. NULL values don't occupy any space in a PostgreSQL table, so you need not worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/190306/4808122) there are three options to implement *inheritance* in a relational database.

IMO the only practicable way to be used in *data warehouse* is the **Table-Per-Hierarchy** option, which merges all entities in one table.

The reason is not only the *performance gain by saving the joins*. In *data warehouse* often the historical view of the data is important. Think, *how would you model a change in a subtype in some entity?*

An important thing is to define a **discriminator column** which uniquely defines the source entity.