# groupBy a row that can have one or both of two columns non-null

Tags: php, laravel, join, group-by

I have 3 tables:

1. Shifts {vehicled_id, user_id, subdriver_id)
2. Users {user_id, subdriver_id)
3. Vehicles {vehicle_id}

I want to group Shifts when I join with Users and Vehicles but some shifts only have user_id or subdriver_id and some have both.

[This is the picture of shifts tables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pmgm.jpg)

The result I want is a groupBy of vehicle_id and:
If it has only user_id or subdriver_id it will return {user_id, vehicle_id, shift_id (it can be an array)}
or {subdriver_id, vehicle_id, shift_id (it can be an array)}.
If it has both user and subdriver it will return {user_id, vehicle_id, shift_id(it can be array)}

shift_id is based on user_id and vehicle_id or subdriver_id and vehicle_id.

How can I groupBy and return a result like this?

Comment: [mre] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) PS Your table design is a common anti-pattern for DB subtypes. [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097) [How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190296/3404097)

Comment: "I" is always capitalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use CASE statement which goes through multiple conditions and return a value based on respective condition.

```
DB::table('shifts')
->select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN shifts.user_id IS NULL THEN shifts.subdriver_id WHEN shifts.subdriver_id IS NULL THEN shifts.user_id ELSE shifts.user_id END as user_id, shifts.vehicle_id, GROUP_CONCAT(shifts.id) as shift_id'))
->leftJoin('users as u1','u1.id','shifts.user_id')
->leftJoin('users as u2','u2.subdriver_id','shifts.subdriver_id')
->groupBy('shifts.vehicle_id')
->get();
```

Comment: tks bro this worked for me