# PostgreSQL representing different types of relations

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I have a PostgreSQL database for representing relational data. In my case the tables are as follows:

- **User**: Basic user
- **Issuer**: Upgraded user
- **Badge**: Badge to issue, can only be created by issuer, and can be issued to any type of user

The relation between the tables are as follows:

- **Issuer - User**: one to one, basic info of issuers are held in User table, issuer related info are held in Issuer table
- **Issuer - Badge**: one to many, an issuer can create multiple unique badges
- **Badge - User**: many to many, one user can hold multiple diff. badges and a badge can be issued to multiple diff. users

1. Should I combine User and Issuer tables into one and add a field to indicate the role of the user, or should I keep them separated? Note that Issuer has multiple fields that are unique to them (such as createdBadges). This way User will have both createdBadges and issuedBadges fields.
2. Should I create separate table for indicating the relation between Badge and User called Issuances, or should I just have array references to each other?

I want better logical coherency, better management, and higher efficiency.

Comment: [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097)
[How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190296/3404097)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `issuer` gets a `NOT NULL` foreign key to `users` with a unique constraint on it
- `badge` gets a `NOT NULL` foreign key to `issuer`
- a junction table `user_badge` has `NOT NULL` foreign keys to both `users` and `badge` and a primary key that is composed of both foreign keys

Don't call a table `user`, since that is a reserved word in SQL.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understand the 2nd and 3rd points but have few questions remaining regarding 1st. With the 1st one, there is no straightforward way to know the role of the user, so I believe LEFT JOIN needs to be done everytime a user's all information needs to be retrieved. Is that kind of a necessary overhead? Also would also storing a foreign key in `users` to `issuer`, with a possibility of null value could improve the solution or make it worse?

Comment: Yes, an outer join is the way to go. Having a foreign key from `users` to `issuer` would be an alternative, but I prefer `NOT NULL` columns. The outer join would be just the same.