# Why not always use One-to-Many instead of Many-to-Many?

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many, relational-database, relationship, one-to-many

I'm trying to learn about postgres and relationships. So let's take a very common example. Say we have a Users table and a Products table. I know that the classic way to go about it is to phrase the relationship as **One User has many Products** and **One Product has many Users** which will result in a Many2Many relationship. But what's the advantage of that over just going **One User can have many Products** and **Many Products can belong to one User**, which would give out a One2Many relationship from the User perspective?

---

Comment: It takes three tables to model the User/Product Many-to-Many relationship you describe in your question.  If User/Product is One-to-Many in one direction or the other, then you need only two tables.

Comment: @MikeOrganek so in case of Many-to-Many, where we need 3 tables, there's a User table with user_id & user_name; Product table with product_id & product_name and a 3rd table, let's say Orders, where you have user_id & product_id as columns. So in Orders table, user with id 1 will have 3 entries, if he had ordered 3 products, user with id 2, 4 entries, etc. But in One-to-Many, User table would have user_id, user_name and a products array with product_ids from Products table and Products table would only have product_id, and product_name. So the question is why is one better than the other?

Comment: Do not use array columns.

Comment: @MikeOrganek Then how would One-To-Many work in this case? User table will have multiple rows with the same user_id and different product_ids from Products table?

Comment: It would not work because it does not work.  Use the many-to-many join table.  Do not use array columns.

Comment: In a logical design your description of M:M between products:users is correct. However, (afaik) this cannot be implemented in a physical model by any RDBMS. The solution is introduction of a 3rd table - a resolution table. Let's call it  UP (User_Product). Now this table actually contains two 1:M relationships:  User:UP and 1:M Product:UP.  This **is** your *One2Many relationship from the User perspective* and also a *One2Many relationship from the Product perspective*.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve, for example, Let me explain relationships in a relational database with a different example.
There are three different types of relationships.
Now for example in a social media app.
One to one, a user can only have one profile. This relationship is between the profile table and the user table.

One to many, a user can write multiple posts, this relationship is known as one to many between the user table and the post table.
many to many, now when a user can follow multiple tags, and each tag can be followed by multiple users this represents a many to many relationship.
You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74605131/postgresql-representing-different-types-of-relations) previous post in StackOverflow for more context.

So if you want your product table to be associated with many users, and for many users to own different products then a manytomany field is more appropriate.