# SQL table with almost same fields - Can i reduce duplication?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm creating a school sql system and have this table planning:

[image]

Note that i have almost the same tables for students and professor, it only differs by course column. Is there a way to create like a unique users table to join both and differs it only by these fields?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put common columns into 1 Table (i.e Users) and a separate table for category specific columns.

Example:

```
Users
========
Id
Name
DateOfBirth


Students
==========
UserId (FK to Users.Id)
Classes


Professors
==========
UserId (FK to User.Id)
```

There are plenty of approaches, but this is just one of them if you want to normalize your database.

Answer (score 0):

I that you're asking if you can join different tables together if they don't have the exact same primary keys.
The answer is yes in some cases. You can't have two primary keys of the same name in a database.

So you could do

```sql
SELECT students.id, professors.id
FROM students
INNER JOIN
on Professors WHERE students.id=professors.id
```

This issue with this is that the data type for the primary key in students might be different from the data type of the primary key in professors.

Below is a rough code for how you could do it. I doubt this specifically will work, but you get the idea. I'm selecting everything from Students and Joining it to professors. This would read as a huge table.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Students
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Professors
```

What I recommend doing, is creating a third table and just insert data from both the Students and Professors table. Joining them, to me, would be more troublesome.

By creating a new table you can just have multiple Primary Keys with differing data times. This table would also be big, but rather than creating some super complex joining formula, you can just insert the data piece by piece.

Then you can do something like:

```
INSERT into NewTable Students.ID
SELECT FROM Students...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some things like this:

```
 userInfo
 ============
 id
 name
 dateofbirthday
 email
 cellphone
 password
 classs
 .
 .
 .
 userType => student/professor
```

then other tables:

```
 CoursTable
 ============
 id
 coursName
 .
 .
 .
```

and then if you want show which Student or Professor has which course should make a pivot table between userInfo table and CoursTable

```
 userInfo_CoursTable
 ===============

 UserInfo_id
 CourseTable_id
```