# Mapping EER to Relational model. Mandatory participation of superclass with (Mandatory; Disjoint) subclasses

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, relational-model

I have a Superclass A that has a 1:* (one-to-many) relationship with another entity (X) and the participation of A is mandatory. A has two subclasses with their own distinct attributes, B and C. The superclass-subclass hierarchy is organised in a way that the participation constraint is mandatory and there can't be an overlap, it's either B or C with no 'abstract' A.

While mapping it to relational model, I've created just two separate tables (relations) for B and C, and placed their primary keys as foreign keys to the X entity. Then I've realised that the foreign keys must be nullable since it can be either B or C. However, it has created an undesirable option to have both foreign keys as nulls or to have two of them at the same time.

Another option that I can think of is to create a single relation for both subclasses and add some flags (isB and isC), but it'll be messy if the number of attributes of each of the subclasses will grow. Moreover, it'll generate a lot of null values.

What do I do? What's the best practice to accommodate such kind of situations and map it to relational model?

[Link to an example diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBuGX.png)

Comment: A 1-to-n relationship is a bit like a parent-child relationship: and the FK should be in the child, not in the parent... and then of course you would not have that conundrum at all.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL--text. [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284)

Comment: Radio button FKs are an anti-pattern for DB subtyping. Both are faqs. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably. [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097)
[How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190296/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

While mapping, leave just the two subclasses (especially if they have many attributes), leave the foreign keys in the X entity and make them nullable.

A check constraint for your X entity:

```
CHECK (
    (B_ID IS NOT NULL AND C_ID IS NULL) OR
    (B_ID IS NULL AND C_ID IS NOT NULL)
)
```

Comment: As I have tried to tell you in a comment to the question, that is the *wrong* pattern: the FK's belong to the "children" entities.

Comment: Dear @JulioDiEgidio, what do you mean by saying that the foreign keys belong to the children entities? In my case, the X entity is the child entity, as it is located on the "many" side of the relationship. 
Or do you mean that the subclasses should be mapped in a way that the primary key of the superclass A is placed as a foreign key in B and C tables? If so, then I don't see how the mandatory participation and the disjoint constraint are ensured.

Comment: If A is a super-class (the "parent" entity) and B and C are the "children" entities, then the FKs go into the B and C entities, not the other way round: and that is how FK's work.  So, if you have a constraint such as the one you are mentioning, it is indeed your model that is upside-down: A is actually a "child" of either of those two.