# Will it be an anti-pattern to suffix table name with a numeric id

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design, anti-patterns

**Context:**

I have a `Game` table which is a master table and it will hold pre-defined game rows, say:

[image: Game table]

Now, I could create a `Game_Detail` table, that will contain game played state/history/data specific to games like this:

[image: Game_Detail table]

**Dilemma**:

Individually these games will have heterogeneous data, and since I'm not using a NoSQL/Document database, this can't be stored efficiently in a single table. Thus I'm thinking of using the following approach:

**Suffix the table name with the foreign key/id of the game**. i.e.:

[image: Game_Detail_001 table]

[image: Game_Detail_002 table]

**Some thoughts:**

1. Since code will access only the design-time/config-defined games, no dynamic Table name concatenation will be required, and thus no ugly code or performance concerns
2. Again, since this all is at design time, ORM will not have a problem. I am using Sequalize with Node.js
3. This may perform better, as keeping data in same table will help i/o

**Extra:**

1. Don't want to use JSON, key/property lookup table for obvious reasons
2. I believe this is a common scenario and I've tackled this in the past, but I'm not able to think clearly and thus need some help. Specially, If this is an anti-pattern, and will have any problems down the line?

Comment: No this is not an antipattern, but because Relational databases treats semantic data it will be more appropriate that the suffix would be a word instead of a number...

Comment: This question is close to being a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/695752/20860

Comment: What is the 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097)
[How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190296/3404097) etc [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) BUT PS Yes or no questions are seldom useful & seldom ask what the asker actually wants answered. PS Please don't put something only in the title.

Comment: Don't worry about JSON for data that does note partake in `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY`, etc.  Just as you would not worry about how pixels are stored in an image in a `BLOB`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do the following:

```
game
- id PK
- name Text
- ...

player
- id PK
- name Text
- ...

property
- id PK
- name Text

game_detail
- game FK(game.id)
- player FK(player.id)
- property FK(property.id)
- value Real
- PK(game,player,property)
```

Comment: This is Entity-Attribute-Value, which has its own problems. Your example assumes that all the values are `REAL` data type.

Comment: This is called entity-attribute-value (EAV), and while it is sometimes necessary, it's considered an **anti-pattern**: something to avoid.