# Database design for multiple similar types?

Tags: database, database-design

Say I have two question types: Multiple Choice and Range. A Range question allows users to answer by specifying a range of values in their answer (1-10 or 2-4 for example).

I inherited a database where the answers to these question types are stored in the same table which is structured like so:

```
Answers
-------
Id
QuestionId
choice
range_from
range_to
```

This results in data like below:

```
1   1   null   1     10
2   1   null   2     4
3   2   Pants  null  null
4   2   Hat    null  null
```

Does it make sense to include columns from every answer type in the answer table? Or should they be broken out into separate tables?

This is a very slimmed-down version of my real database.  In reality there are about 8 question types, so with every answer there are several columns that are left unused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Techniques for database inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386652/techniques-for-database-inheritance)

Comment: Imo you should have one main table that says what kind of question it is, then the question itself will be stored in a table that has only the fields it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it make sense to include columns from every answer type in the answer table?

This is "all classess in the same table" strategy for implementing inheritance, which is suitable for small number of classes. As the number of classes grows, you might consider one of the [other strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037398/533120). There is no predefined "cut-off point" for that - you'll have to measure and decide for yourself.

The alternative would be an EAV-like system [as proposed by blotto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16349843/533120), but that would shift the enforcement of data consistency away from the DBMS. This is a valid solution if you don't know the structure of data at design-time and want to avoid DML at run-time, but if you do know the structire of data at design-time better stick with inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a single field that represents the 'type' of question, that seems best suited in the Question table ( not the Answer table).  For example:

```
question_type ENUM('choice', 'range', 'type_3', 'type_4'..)
```

Then make a one-to-many link ( a join table ) that represents the Question-to-Answers relationship

```
AnswerId (pk) | QuestionId (fk)
 1             1
 2             1
 3             2
 4             2
```

Finally, your Answer table is a collection of values for each Answer . It can designate each record more specifically by having its own ENUM.

```
answer_type ENUM('low_range', 'high_range', 'choice', etc)

Id (pk)| AnswerId (fk) | Type        |  Value
1        1              low_range       1
2        1              high_range      10
3        2              low_range       2
4        2              high_range      4
5        3              choice          Pants 
6        4              choice          Hat
```

This is much more scalable, and basically pivots the fields in your previous table to values in the answers table.  So you can always add new 'Type's both for questions an answers without adding new fields to the schema.