# Structure of database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, design-patterns, database-design

I'm creating a gaming website that will have a database of items found in a game (several thousand) and I'm wondering what best practice would be for the database structure.

There are 5 item types: weapons, armor, potions, quest items and junk. Each of these has unique attributes that don't apply to other items. For example, weapons can be different types (i.e. two-handed, main-hand, off-hand), armor can be different weights (plate, leather), etc.

Everything is an 'item', but I'm wondering if I should I have a single table of items, i.e.:

```
item id, item_type ... item_weapon_type_id, item_armor_weight_id
```

Thus having all possible attributes in one table.

Or separate tables for each item type, i.e.:

```
weapon_id, weapon_type, weapon_name
```

I am wondering this since each item type has a number of unique attributes, which means a single table of items would have a lot of columns, many of which don't apply to 80% of the items in the table.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You could do some sort of inheritance in the database  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386652/techniques-for-database-inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that will be useful having a base table for item types, called `Item-Base-Type`, containing shared properties of all item types. 
Per item type(like shield) there will be a separate table ( like `shield-type`) with one-one relationship to the `Item-Base-Type`.
`Item` table that contains all items of the game will have a foreign key to the `Item-Base-Type`.
I think you will need some helper tables like `Effect` be added to the model.
`is-quest-item` will be a property of `Item` table.
Having a look at [the wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Items) may helps.

[image: template of game items]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to make this for me, very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Have two tables:

**Weapons**

- WeaponId
- Description

**WeaponType**

- WeaponTypeId
- WeaponId
- Description (One handed, two handed etc)

This way you can have the same weapon but equipped to one hand or two hands.

Separating out the tables will normalize the database and also improve performance. For example, you are not selecting repeating rows when you want a basic list of Weapons available.

Comment: Thanks for the response Darren, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can make two tables:

1. items

   - id - PK
   - type
   - name
   - some_attribute
   - some_other_attribute
2. item_attributes

   - item_id - PK
   - attribute_name - PK
   - attribute_value

Put the common attributes (e.g. price,weight...) in the `items` table, and the rest of them in the attributes table.

Also, don't worry too much if some of the fields in `items` are not used for all of the types. 2-3 enum fields should be sufficient to describe the types, armor 'heavy-ness', weapon types, etc... of the items (at least in the games I have seen).