# ER Diagram Entity without attribute

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, er-diagram

I have designed an er-diagram and have an entity without any attributes. I need this entity (Item) to create a many-to-many relationshop but I guess there is a way to make this more efficient and getting rid of the entity without attributes.

ER DIAGRAM:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I can see from your diagram your `Item` isn't just entity without attributes. It's a base type for your `BAGEL` and `DRINK` (you can think of this relationship as `inheritance` in OOP languages).

There are some techniques to work with [inheritance in database world](https://stackoverflow.com/a/386683/2253302). So this `Item` is not a problem for `ER-diagram`.

Answer (score 1):

`ITEM` should have at least one attribute - an identifier.  A supertype's primary key can be reused as a foreign primary key in its subtypes.