# selecting a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, schema

I have a mysql database and some tables.

One table is **Products**: Its columns are `prod_id`, `prod_type`.

**Prod_types** are `mobile` or `laptop` or `book`.

Each of them have different attributes (eg: *publisher, author for books, battery_condition, model for laptop* etc).

Should I **store all the data** in the **Products** table by adding columns like 'author', 'model' etc and keep null for those columns which don't apply to my product.

For example for an entry with `prod_type='book'` , 'model', 'batter_condition' etc will be null. Or should I create different tables for 'book', 'mobile' and 'laptop' ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Please try to lay out your question in a way that other people can read it. As it stands, you are unlikely to get help as people won't be able to understand what you have written.

Comment: in general, you shouldn't have a bunch of "optional" fields in a relational database. Create suitable tables for them and link to them.

Comment: Have a read of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386652/techniques-for-database-inheritance, which detail a few approaches and their pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Create new tables for Book, Mobile and Laptop. Have the product_id attribute in each of those tables. This product_id attribute is a foreign key to the primary key of table products, which is product_id as well.

Storing all data in products will result in a lot of NULL fields and will make the data storage inefficient.